# Is it possible to construct a compact operator $A$ such that all polynomials of degree $1$ are in the nullspace of $I-A$?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, operator-theory, compact-operators

I would like to construct a compact linear operator $A:X\to Y$ such that
$$
(I-A)\varphi = 0
$$
for all $\varphi = a_0 + a_1x$, i.e. for all polynomials of degree 1? Here $X$ and $Y$ should be some function spaces on the domain $[0,1]$. This is because I want an intuitive example of an operator $L=I-A$ where $A$ is compact and $L$ has a two-dimensional nullspace.

Is it possible to specify an operator $A$ and spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that the above holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X = Y = C^0[0,1]$ (with the sup-norm), and look at the linear operator $L:X\to Y$ given by
$$
(Lf)(x) = f(x) - f(1)x + (x-1)f(0)
$$
which, geometrically, shears and vertically translates the graph of $f$ so that $(Lf)(0) = (Lf)(1) = 0$. This makes
$$
(Af)(x) = f(1)x - (x-1)f(0)
$$
so $A$ gives the straight line between $(0,f(0))$ and $(1, f(1))$.

Comment: .. which is just linear interpolation :)

Comment: Excellent thanks!

Comment: Ehmm, how do we know $A$ is compact?

Comment: @csss I don't know exactly what definition you're using, but I'll go with "The image of the closed unit ball is relatively compact". The image of the closed unit ball is the set of functions $ax + b$ with $-1\leq b\leq 1$ and $-1-b\leq a \leq 1+b$ (this comes from $-1\leq f(0), f(1)\leq 1$). The set $V\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ of possible values of $a, b$ is compact in $\Bbb R^2$, and the function $\Bbb R^2\to C^0[0,1]$ that takes $(a, b)$ to $ax + b$ is continuous, so the image of $V$ is also compact.

Comment: Ok I get it now thanks!

Comment: @Arthur Could we also say that $A$ is compact because it has finite rank..i.e. it only acts on two dimensions; constant functions and linear functions?

Comment: @csss You are right that it has finite rank, and we could use that. However, it is not because it only "acts on" two dimensions. It acts on the entire space. Instead, its _image_ only has two dimensions.

Comment: @Arthur Ok great!